# Eliminate `boost::xtime` in `boost::condition::timed_wait`

Tags: c++, boost

We currently have lots of code of the following form:

```
boost::xtime t;
boost::xtime_get (&t, POV_TIME_UTC);
t.sec += 3 ;
m_Event.timed_wait (lock, t);
```

or even:

```
boost::xtime t;
boost::xtime_get (&t, POV_TIME_UTC);
t.nsec += 50000000 ;
m_Event.timed_wait (lock, t);
```

(Yes, that's without checking `t.nsec` for overflow. *:shudder:*)

where `POV_TIME_UTC` is defined as either `boot::TIME_UTC` or `boost::TIME_UTC_` depending on boost version.

Is it safe to replace these with:

```
m_Event.timed_wait (lock, boost::posix_time::seconds(3))
```

and

```
m_Event.timed_wait (lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50))
```

respectively?

Also, does someone happen to know what minimum version of boost this requires? My research indicates boost 1.35, but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Boost 1.35 added support for relative timeouts in Boost.Thread. Yes, the canonical way to specify a relative time is with `boost::posix_time::time_duration` (which is the base class of `posix_time::seconds` and `posix_time::milliseconds`).

If you need documentation as to the required Boost version, the [changes in 1.35](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/thread/changes.html#thread.changes.version_2_0_0___changes_since_boost_1_34) (a.k.a. changes since 1.34), mentions support for relative timeouts. If that's too vague for your purposes, compare the [1.34 documentation for `condition`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/boost/condition.html) to the [1.35 documentation for `condition_variable_any`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable_any). (There's a `typedef` that allows you to keep the type name "`condition`" in 1.35.) Version 1.34 documents only absolute time versions of `timed_wait()`, while version 1.35 has templates for versions taking relative times. A time parameter that is neither an `xtime` nor a `system_time` is assumed to be a relative time.

Be aware that `timed_wait()` was deprecated in Boost 1.50 -- the replacements are `wait_for()` and `wait_until()`, for relative and absolute timeouts respectively. <del>As of Boost 1.53 the declarations of `timed_wait()` are suppressed unless specifically requested via a `#define`. So what you propose is valid for versions 1.35 through 1.52.</del> *Edit: Apparently, the deprecated functions were not removed on the documented schedule. However, they are still deprecated, so once you can establish 1.50 as a minimum version, it would be prudent to convert to the newer functions.*

Comment: "As of Boost 1.53 the declarations of timed_wait() are suppressed unless specifically requested via a #define" - can you provide a source? From what I see in the code (boost 1.62), while the code itself requires BOOST_THREAD_USES_DATETIME to be defined, this in turn seems to be defined by boost based on an opt-out mechanism (either setting BOOST_THREAD_VERSION to 4 or higher - default is 2 - or defining BOOST_THREAD_DONT_USE_DATETIME).

Comment: My source for that is the documentation for boost 1.51 (scroll up after following the the "changes in 1.35" link in my answer). However, I now see that there seems to have been a last-minute change to 1.53 that undid the planned removal, but that did not update (all of) the documentation. So I guess those functions are still readily available options. I'll update my answer.